# Declaring subclasses variable in superclass

Tags: iphone, superclass

My superclass have 8 subclasses such that variables in first 4 subclasses are of a kind and remaining 4 subclasses are of another kind. Should it be right practice to declare all variables in my superclass with getter and setter method, and then access from respective subclasses? What will be advantage and disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say since we don't see what the exact situation is.

For the way you describe it it would probably be best to make this 3-level subclassing

```
                   superclass
                    (empty)
                       |
         --------------+--------------
         |                            | 
   subclass_typeA                subclass_typeB
(4 type A properties)          (4 type B properties)
```

Then each of these sublclass_typeX has it's own 4 subclasses

**PROS**: readability, easier later modifications

**CONS**: more work for you in the beginning

EDIT: it would most definetly be the right practice to declare all properties in superclass. In that case you could use just one class with added *enumerated* property called `classType` but that has nothing to do with OOP anymore.